# Spring file I/O for WAR export in Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, file-io, tomcat7

I want to do file I/O in a Spring application.

I went to the XML path but all I get is a `BeanCreationException` error once it runs.

---

1. I made `file-locations.properties` inside `my_spring_app/src/main/resources` and here are its contents:

   ```
   # location of desired files

   dir.server=/home/user/webapps/my_spring_app/WEB-INF/classes/
   dir.local=D:/resources
   ```
2. They said to modify the `application-context.xml` where the `.properties` file will be declared so Spring can recognize it (???).

   ```
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:file-locations.properties" properties-ref="filePathProps" />
   ```
3. Call the `.properties` file in my `Service` layer for file I/O.

   ```
   @Value("#{filePathProps.dir.local}")
   private String PATH_FILES;

   System.out.println(PATH_FILES); // so far null
   ```

   I have tried numerous combinations: `@Value("#{filePathProps.dir.local}")`, `@Value("${filePathProps.dir.local}")`, `@Value("#{dir.local}")`, `@Value("${dir.local}")` and all of them returned the error.
4. I will use `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` to these files.

---

The complete `application-context.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.5xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

  <!-- Auto-detect components -->

  <context:component-scan base-package="my.spring.app" />

  <bean id="MyService1"
    class="my.spring.app.service.impl.MyService1Impl" />
  <bean id="MyService2Service"
    class="my.spring.app.service.impl.MyService2ServiceImpl" />
  <bean id="MyService3Service"
    class="my.spring.app.service.impl.MyService3ServiceImpl" />

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <!-- Application Message Bundle -->
  <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
  </bean>

  <!-- files??? -->
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:file-locations.properties"
    properties-ref="filePathProps" />

</beans>
```

Here is the `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>my_spring_app</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Error pages -->
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/400.jsp</location>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/403.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/405.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/500.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/exception.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Here is the `spring-servlet.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="my.package.controller" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="my.package.service" />

  <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <!--This tag allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (all extensions 
    etc) -->
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <mvc:resources location="/resources/**, classpath:resources"
    mapping="/resources/**" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/*" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/*" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/*" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/weka/**" location="/resources/weka/*" />

</beans>
```

---

Partial stack trace ([full here](http://pastebin.com/ePMKeLdP)):

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.package.service.CalcService my.package.controller.CalcController.calcService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calcService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void my.package.service.impl.MyServiceImpl.setMyService2(my.package.service.MyService2); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calcArffService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String my.package.service.impl.MyService2Impl.PATH_FILES; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'filePath' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

I made a POJO called `FilePath`:

```
public class FilePath {

  private String filePath;

  public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
  }

  public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "FilePath [filePath=" + filePath + "]";
  }

}
```

I added the following to my `spring-servlet.xml` or `application-context.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="src/main/resources" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:file-locations.properties" />
<bean id="filePaths"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:file-locations.properties" />
</bean>
<bean class="ph.edu.upm.agila.gtmeren.bosom.domain.FilePath">
  <property name="filePath" value="${filePath}" />
</bean>
```

But even if I put these new code, or this in `application-context.xml`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file-locations.properties" />
<bean class="my.package.FilePath">
    <property name="filePath" value="file-location.properties" />
</bean>
```

The output of `System.out.println(PATH_FILES);` is `${dir.local}`.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace. `${dir.local}` should work.

Comment: Also, what class is the `@Value` annotated field in? There must be a bean for it.

Comment: It looks to me like you are mixing context files. Make the bean with `@Value` be loaded by the context that has the `component-scan` and `property-placeholder`.

Comment: You mean to insert `<context:component-scan base-package="my.spring.app" /> <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:file-locations.properties" class="my.spring.app"/>` in `application-context.xml`?

Comment: It looks like you already have them there. What context does your `DispatcherServlet` load?

Comment: If you mean by "context" I am loading a Service layer class where I read and write the files.

Comment: No I mean context configuration files, typically your XML Spring configuration files.

Comment: I added the contents of `web.xml` and `spring-servlet.xml` I'm sorry I can't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Let go by steps.

1. Define property placeholder

   `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:file-locations.properties"/>`
2. Access the property using `dir.server` etc
3. Inject value using $
4. Hence your bean would look like following

   @Value("${dir.local}") 
   private String PATH_FILES;
5. Now the real question is whether property is getting loaded or not.

   1. if you are testing it after deploying to server make sure the file is in `/WEB-INF/classes/file-locations.properties`
   2. If you are doing a junit sing eclipse make sure file in project-properties-> java build path -> sources tab. `src/main/resources` is included with option included all

   **EDITED**

Add configurations in web.xml its missing in web.xml, if application-context.xml is in spring directory inside classpath, you need to add context parameter in web.xml as follows

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: I've done #s 1 - 4 and I am currently running the Spring application in my Eclipse and I do not use jUnit tests. The output of `System.out.println(PATH_FILES);` is `${dir.local}` :( How do I solve this?

Comment: I checked the `tomcat/webapps/my_spring_app` and yes, `file-locations.properties` is inside `WEB-INF/classes`. Please help me

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the `<context-param>` will be useless as OP doesn't have a `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, not an issue. I had overlooked ContextLoaderListener

Comment: Still, the `ContextLoaderListener` might load fine, but the `DispatcherServlet` will not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimano, oh yeah it also doesn't point spring-servlet.xml

Comment: It doesn't have to. By default, `DispatcherServlet` looks for a file named `<whatever-the-servlet-name-is>-servlet.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) before you continue. If not all of it, you should at least read about the Context Hierarchy and which `ApplicationContext` is loaded by which web application component.

Currently, your `application-context.xml` serves absolutely no purpose. Nothing in your application, as you've shown it, is using it. Your `DispatcherServlet` is loading its configuration from `spring-servlet.xml`. You need to declare your `property-placeholder` in there.

The field itself should be

```
@Value("${dir.local}")
private String PATH_FILES;
```

The Spring documentation explains [SpEL expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) as well in much detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it without any errors:

1. I put the files I need for I/O in `src/resources`.
2. After running Tomcat, I search where these files go after and they are in `C:/tomcat/webapp/my_app/WEB-INF/classes/resources`.
3. I made a function to concatenate `C:/tomcat/webapp/my_app/WEB-INF/classes/resources` to my files.
4. For example I want write to a file, I just do:

   ```
   String filePath = myService.getAbsolutePath() + "file.dat";
   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
   ```

   where `.getAbsolutePath()` is implemented to just return the file path we go in the `MyService` class!

Note: once uploaded in the server, just repeat number two - search in the server where the files are placed and substitute them to the content of `.getAbsolutePath()`!

There you go!